# DocuSign API : Captive recipient

Tags: docusignapi

I am using SOAP based API call "CreateAndSendEnvelope" to create an envelope into my DocuSign account for remote recipients. I haven't used captive recipients and I also have not created any envelopes from templates so far.

My main reason for not creating envelopes from templates is my document to be included in the DocuSign envelope is not static, it gets generated dynamically based upon certain conditions.

If I need to include recipients as captive recipients in an envelope, do I always have to create an envelope from a template?
As I mentioned earlier, I cannot create an envelope using template as then every time I need to create an envelope, I need to create a template first.

Is there a way to create an envelope first and then redirect a recipient to a signing page/console/URL?

I assume that as remote recipients, captive recipients need not be the DocuSign account users.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can definitely embed recipients without using any templates - they are two separate, unrelated things.  To configure embedded recipients through the SOAP API you just need to set their captive info.

On each recipient there is **CaptiveInfo** property which has a **clientUserId** element that you need to set if you want to embed them.  It's up to you what value to use for each recipient, but you just need to remember that info when later requesting the URL for them.

There's a whole page on the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center) that discusses Embedding functionality and even though it's tailored for the REST API it will still give you some needed info:

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign

Then to link it back to the SOAP API you can view sample code through the DocuSign SOAP SDK that's up on GitHub.  It has 5 sample projects, written in `Java`, `PHP`, `.NET`, `Ruby`, and `Salesforce` (apex).

https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK